# Different values when using summary() and max, min and mean in R

Tags: r

I am trying to get the max, min and mean of a column in a data frame. When i use max, min and mean I get some values which are different from the values when I used, summary()

```
> max(count1,na.rm=TRUE)
[1] 202034

> min(count1,na.rm=TRUE)
[1] 0

> mean(count1,na.rm=TRUE)
[1] 8498.78

> summary(count1,na.rm=TRUE) 
Min.  1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max.    NA's 
0        1555    3668    8499    8535  202000   58297
```

Comment: Compare `summary(mtcars$mpg) ;mean(mtcars$mpg)` and then `options(digits=10); summary(mtcars$mpg) ;mean(mtcars$mpg) `

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `summary.default` function has a `digits` argument:

```
summary(object, ..., digits = max(3, getOption("digits")-3))
```

Since the default `getOptions("digits")` is `7`, you get only `4` digits. Everything after that is rounded (with a call to `signif()`). You can change as proposed by [user20650](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2250190/user20650) setting e.g.

```
options(digits=10)
```

Or if you want the change just for this particular call:

```
summary(count1, digits = 10)
```